# How to use explicit SSL with System.Net.Mail SMTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, smtp, system.net.mail

I've seen a lot of examples of implicit SSL (for use with the deprecated `System.Web.Mail`), but I'm using `System.Net.Mail` and would like a code example for how to send SMTP emails via explicit SSL.

My current `sendEmail` code is below - note that if I set `EnableSsl = true`, server returns a 500 error and the email is never sent. I assume because this is implicit SSL, which `System.Net.Mail` does not support:

```
using System.Net.Mail;
...

    public static void SendEmail(string emailbody)
    {

        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage("myDomain@me.com", "yourDomain@me.com");

        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

        mailMessage.Body = emailbody;

        mailMessage.Subject = "My email";

        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.me.com", 25);

        // if false, email sends. If true, email does not send, server returns 500 error
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;

        smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
    }
```

Comment: What port does your email provider use for SSL email?

Comment: Unsure, but I would guess 465

Comment: instead of `25` as port number, can you give the actual SSL enabled port number of your mail server ? (also set `EnableSsl` to `true`). You can also see the exact error message the remote server is returning. This can help in trouble shooting. We have used the following command line program (http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/) for trouble shooting the mail issues. In our experience, in most cases, there is some setting change that is required in the mail server. (For e.g., to relax relaying restrictions, etc). So, the exact error message from the mail server is crtiical.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/950260/you-cannot-use-system-net-mail-smtpclient-to-send-an-e-mail-message-wi

You can supposedly use cdo.sys, but it's really old and I don't believe it's supported anymore. I'm also not sure it's available or usable since it came with Windows 2000.

Your best bet would be to setup an actual mail server to handle talking to the outside world and talk to it with your unencrypted port 25 connection. If you have a small box to dedicate, Postfix is a free, very lightweight and very robust SMTP server that would work nicely.